# python: testing arrays and printing the name

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am analysing a design structure matrix (DSM) for dependences of elements in a manufacturing process. After some matrix operations I end up with two arrays which are the sum of columns and rows of the resulting matrix:

```
SOC = array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])
SOR = array([6, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1])
```

The corresponding positions in each array are indexed into arrays for the following six items (which correspond to the items in the original design structure (I/O) matrix)

```
A = (SOC[0], SOR[0])
B = (SOC[1], SOR[1])
C = (SOC[2], SOR[2])
D = (SOC[3], SOR[3])
E = (SOC[4], SOR[4])
F = (SOC[5], SOR[5])
ITEM = [A, B, C, D, E, F]
```

I then want to test each of the items based four criteria rules and sort them into four more arrays

```
cr = []
sh = []
pr = []
ct = []
result = [cr, sh, pr, ct]

for i in ITEM[0:5]:
    if i[0]>3 and i[1]>3:
        cr.append(i)
    if i[0]>3 and i[1]<=3:
        sh.append(i)
    if i[0]<=3 and i[1]<=3:
        pr.append(i)
    if i[0]<=3 and i[1]>3:
        ct.append(i)
```

the resulting array almost works

```
result = [[], [], [(2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)], [(1, 6)]]
```

Five of the six items were sorted correctly (one is missing). However **what I really need at the end is a list of the ITEMS (variable name) and which category they belong to.** 
I've seen that trying to rename variables based on their definition gets ugly. I've been trying to find different syntaxes for printing the results but I don't know what I don't know. I though about copying the array ITEMs and converting it to a string then printing the corresponding item title. I feel like I'm complicating the crap out of this.

**Can anyone advise a simpler way to reach my goal?**

Comment: Can you add what the output you want to get to would look like? I feel like and `OrderedDict`could help you, but want to make sure I understand what you want

Comment: ITEM = list(zip(SOC, SOR)) is better to create your ITEM variable, especially if SOC/SOR are long

Comment: One element is missing because ITEM[0:5] does not contain ITEM[5].

Comment: Iterate with `for i,v in enumerate(ITEM):`.  That gives both tuple to test and its index in ITEM.

Comment: I'm using an analysis to categorize the different items based on their relationships in the matrix. Your answers helped a lot. It looks like for further implementation I'll need to learn how to use the lists and dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python variable are ways of referencing objects, not names of the objects.  It isn't easy to go from an object to a variable.  Also when dealing with multiple objects, it's more natural to put them in lists or dictionaries, rather than assign them to variables.

I think this does the same classification:

```
In [95]: SOC = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])
    ...: SOR = np.array([6, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]) 
In [96]: items = list(zip(SOC,SOR))
In [97]: items
Out[97]: [(1, 6), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1)]
In [98]: result = [[] for _ in range(4)]
    ...: for n,i in enumerate(items):
    ...:     if i[0]>3 and i[1]>3:
    ...:         result[0].append((n,i))
    ...:     if i[0]>3 and i[1]<=3:
    ...:         result[1].append((n,i))
    ...:     if i[0]<=3 and i[1]<=3:
    ...:         result[2].append((n,i))
    ...:     if i[0]<=3 and i[1]>3:
    ...:         result[3].append((n,i))
    ...:         
In [99]: result
Out[99]: 
[[],
 [(5, (4, 1))],
 [(1, (2, 2)), (2, (2, 3)), (3, (3, 1)), (4, (3, 2))],
 [(0, (1, 6))]]
```

`result` could be converted to characters with:

```
In [100]: np.array(list('ABCDEF'))
Out[100]: array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='<U1')
In [101]: [[np.array(list('ABCDEF'))[x[0]] for x in y] for y in result]
Out[101]: [[], ['F'], ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A']]
```

or directly in the first loop:

```
In [102]: result = [[] for _ in range(4)]
     ...: for n,i in enumerate(items):
     ...:     if i[0]>3 and i[1]>3:
     ...:         result[0].append('ABCDEF'[n])
     ...:     if i[0]>3 and i[1]<=3:
     ...:         result[1].append('ABCDEF'[n])
     ...:     if i[0]<=3 and i[1]<=3:
     ...:         result[2].append('ABCDEF'[n])
     ...:     if i[0]<=3 and i[1]>3:
     ...:         result[3].append('ABCDEF'[n])
     ...:         
     ...:         
In [103]: result
Out[103]: [[], ['F'], ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, you've explained the syntax well for me!